# How to uninstall Tasktop from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, uninstallation, tasktop

I'm trying to uninstall [Tasktop](http://tasktop.com/) from my Eclipse IDE, but when I select it the uninstall button keeps being disabled (maybe because of some dependent plugin I can't find)

Has anyone had a similar experience? I could use some pointers on how to get this plugin uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

I had other problem with the task top plugin. I followed the conventional way to uninstall the  plugin. Help -> About Eclipse -> Installed Software. The plugin was removed from the list of installed software, but still existed as a plugin, Even after resets.

As a last option I manually removed all com.tasktop.* jars and directories from the eclipse\plugin directory. That seems to do the work without any side effect damage for now.

Of course you will have to close eclipse prior to the above action.

Comment: that works ...one simply has no chance to get to the uninstall button because of the nag-screen (which crashes the whole IDE when clicking cancel). one just has to update the Mylyn integrations afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you going for the uninstall?  If you go to Help -> About Eclipse -> Installed Software, you should be able to uninstall any top-level feature there.  Is this not your experience?

Comment: it happens with any other plugin but tasktop. I guess it's because some other plugin dependes on it but i couldnt figure out wich one since I alredy unistalled all the task releted ones.

Comment: I'm still not sure how you are trying to uninstall.  Please attach a screenshot of what you are trying to do and this should help determine what you can do.

Comment: Here you can find a screenshot http://is.gd/SuIv0l
Has you can see even if tasktop ide integration is selected, the uninstall button keeps being disabled. And this happens with any other package of the tasktop plugin